# android separate rows of a table from database

Tags: android, database

I am trying to make a simple android app that get info of user from database, and I want to separate these info by line between them.

like this:

[image]

here is my code:

```
  public String getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID2, KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL};
        Cursor c = ourDbase.query(TABLE_SCORE, columns, null, null, null, null, null + " DESC");
        String result ="";

        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iEmail= c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + c.getString(iEmail) + "  " + c.getString(iName) + "  -" +  c.getString(iRow)+ "\n"; 
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Wow why would you do this? isn't easier to put everything inside an abject a return a list of that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want something like :

```
1 Jason j@yahoo.com-2 Mark m@yahoo.com-3 Freya f@yahoo.com
```

You can do something like :

```
     for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
                result = result + c.getString(iEmail) + "  " + c.getString(iName) + "  -" +  c.getString(iRow)+ "\n"; 
                result+="-"; //add "-" for each person
            }
```

Please tell me if i miss-understood your question.

**UPDATE**

Looking from your example, you probably want to use a `List` of `person`. If you want this, try :

```
  public List<Person> getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID2, KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL};
        Cursor c = ourDbase.query(TABLE_SCORE, columns, null, null, null, null, null + " DESC");
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iEmail= c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            Person p = new Person();
            p.setEmail(c.getString(iEmail));
            //set other info, like id, name
            people.add(person); 
        }

        return people;
    }
```

Where `person` is a new `public class` with private `id,name and email`.

**UPDATE**

```
public class Person {
   private String name, id, email;
   //create the name,id, email setter - getter or just make those variables public
}
```

This is what class `Person` should look like :

Feel free to ask if you dont understand or i miss understood you.

Comment: insert `result+="\n";` at last in loop

Comment: @MD Thanks. But it seems the thread starter want something else...i will try to clarify first

Comment: @Blaze Tama thanks, what I want exactly is a line after each row just like the image I will try now your answer.

Comment: @user3891365 Yes, combine my updated answer (List<Person>) with a ListView

Comment: @Blaze Tama I have a simple question, what should I add to class person? sorry this is the first time I use listView